# Finding out what DNS server are being used

Tags: dns, dig

Using dig I can query a specific DNS server for some DNS records, for instance

```
dig example.com A @192.168.1.1
```

Where in this instance 192.168.1.1 is my router's ip.

Is there a way, using dig or any other program, to find out what DNS servers my router is using? (when it doesn't have the query cached)

I have limited access to the router due to restrictions of the ISP. So in the web interface I cannot find anything.

Comment: are you asking how to find out which DNS servers your router itself is configured to use, when you don't have full access to the router?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes exactly!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `+trace` option to `dig` to see the entire sequence of queries, from your system to root servers, all the way down to the authoritative servers.

Comment: Great this seems to be what I'm looking when I use it on 8.8.8.8 for example. However when I use it with my router it gives back nothing, just: ;; Received 12 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) in 11 ms. Does this mean it's disabled in the router somehow?

Comment: No, it means either the router has cached that the hostname you're looking up doesn't exist, or that the router doesn't have any referrers configured.

Comment: It could also mean that your router is configured to not answer your queries, which is fairly common in corporate environments, so if you bought a router from eBay and repurposed it for home use you really want to reconfigure it.

Comment: No the router is provided by my ISP and the disabled the admin side of the router for me, so I suppose it's also possible they would have disabled this. But this answers my original question, thanks!

Comment: While `dig +trace` is a very useful command, this does not answer the question at all and I can't see why OP marked it as such. OP asked about ([confirmed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279264/finding-out-what-dns-server-are-being-used#comment485565_279264)) finding the chain of DNS servers that are used when local DNS queries are made. Trace goes from the bottom up, to find an authoritative answer, explicitly bypassing that normal resolution chain. It does nothing to inform the user how their queries are really resolved.